# Change base class fields in derived class with base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, variable-assignment, base-class

I am not sure where I am wrong here, but there seems to be some miss conception from my side.

I have a base class and a derived class and some methods like in this example.

```
class Base {
    public:
    int curr_loc;
    Base(int curr_loc):curr_loc(curr_loc)
    void reset(int curr_loc){
        curr_loc = curr_loc;
    }
}

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    Derived(int curr_loc):Base(curr_loc)
}

Derived a(1);
a.reset(2);
a.curr_loc //is still 1?
```

When I call now "a.curr_loc", I still get 1. I thought that I would override the value with the method reset, but this is done on a different object...

Is there a way to do this without I need to copy the functions of the base class for the derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
class Base {
    public:
    int curr_loc;
    Base(int curr_loc):curr_loc(curr_loc)
    void reset(int curr_loc){
        curr_loc = curr_loc;
    }
}

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    Derived(int curr_loc):Base(curr_loc)
}
```

has syntactic errors.

You need to write

```
class Base {
    public:
    int curr_loc;
    Base(int curr_loc):curr_loc(curr_loc){}
    void reset(int curr_loc){
        Base::curr_loc = curr_loc;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    Derived(int curr_loc):Base(curr_loc) {}
};
```

Pay attention to to the member function reset definition. It should be defined either like

```
    void reset(int curr_loc){
        Base::curr_loc = curr_loc;
    }
```

or like

```
    void reset(int curr_loc){
        this->curr_loc = curr_loc;
    }
```

Otherwise the parameter ciur_loc is assigned to itself in this statement

```
        curr_loc = curr_loc;
```

because it hides the data member with the same name of the class Base.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know that the this keyword works via a pointer... Tried this.curr_loc, which does not work in c++

Answer (score 1):

```
curr_loc = curr_loc;
```

This line does nothing. It assigns a variable to itself. The fact that there's also an instance variable called `curr_loc` is not referenced here, since there's a local variable of the same name shadowing it.

You can either rename the argument to be something else or you can explicitly use `this` to assign.

```
this->curr_loc = curr_loc;
```